# Irreducible sets in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Very basic and silly questions about the notion of an irreducible set in a topological space:

Let $X$ be a topological space. A nonempty subset $Y$ is irreducible if it cannot be expressed as the union $Y = Y_1 \cup Y_2$ of two proper subsets, each of which is closed in $Y$.

I am trying to understand this definition and take very simple cases.

Take $X = \mathbb{R}$ with the open sets being (unions of) open intervals, and $Y = (0,1)$. Then it seems to me that $Y$ is irreducible, since if $Y = [a, b] \cup [c,d]$, then either $a = 0$, in which case the union contains a point not in $Y$, or $a >0$, in which case we can find an element of $Y$ not in the union.

I know I am wrong; and that in $\mathbb{R}$ the only irreducible sets are singletons, but I have no idea where.

Comment: I think you would be using subspace topology here, so a set being open in $Y$ stems from restricting an open subset of $X$ to $Y$: Say $O\subset X$ is open, then $O\cap Y$ is open in $Y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $Y=(0,1)$ we have proper subsets:
$$
Y=(0,0.5]\cup[0.5,1)
$$
These are closed in the subspace topology, since their complements are open, like for instance:
$$
(0,0.5]^c=(0.5,1)
$$